# How can i check the bivariate normality ? (by using sas)

Tags: self-study, sas, normality-assumption

[image]

I am doing part c,i want to ask:

1.)how can i check the bivariate normality?

2.) if one of the variable does not follow normal distribution (by qqplot)
is it a strong evidence for saying the variables are not following multivariate normal?

i have check x1& x2 are following normal distribution by using qqplot